# Windows7 IIS7: zips don't have php5isapi.dll Can I use php.dll instead?

Tags: php, php5, installation, isapi, php53

The page: [How to Install PHP 5.2 on IIS 7and Windows Vista](http://www.maniacomputer.com/WebServer/InstallingPHPonIIS7P2.html) (and a few others) reference a mysterious php5isapi.dll which is not in the Windows install, or the zip files:

```
php-5.3.2-Win32-VC9-x86.zip - VC9 x86 Thread Safe
php-5.3.2-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip - VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe
```

There was another post on stackoverflow that said it's obsolete and replaced by "fastapi" but no instructions mention this.

I *did* find a php.dll in the zip file.  **Can I use that instead of php5isapi.dll?**

It's very frustrating trying to install basic PHP5 on Windows with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, FastCGI is the recommended interface on Windows starting with 5.3.

Is there a reason you can't switch to FastCGI?

As for the DLL, I recall something about the switch to VC9 that made it fun/complex.  Maybe there us a VC6 build somewhere?

Comment: No reason... I can probably switch.  I'm a newbie and just don't know the right way to proceed.  I'll try FastCGI!

Comment: Turns out that they indeed dropped all ISAPI support in 5.3  http://news.php.net/php.internals.win/166

Comment: Just add the "CGI" feature to the IIS component using add/remove windows features and you'll be on the right path

Answer (score 0):

Fast CGI would be best option and Please Use Non thread Safe Version of PHP 5.3 installer/Zip as it is much compatible with windows.